# Mostrar imagens antes de fazer upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um plugin de upload em PHP/CSS do qual o usuário escolhe múltiplas imagens e o campo de upload é estilizado conforme [esse link](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/). Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém preciso fazer com que essas imagens apareçam ao serem selecionadas e que possa ter a opção de escolher qual será a principal antes de fazer o upload. Tem algum meio ou plugin que faça isso?

Escolha as fotos…

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Mostrar Imagem antes de salvar no banco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203629/mostrar-imagem-antes-de-salvar-no-banco)

Comment: Outra resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152396/upload-de-fotos-com-preview-javascript-ajax?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Obrigado Andre, mas o que melhor se adaptou as minhas necessidades foi desse link: http://jsfiddle.net/ERZVC/2/

Comment: Acabei de ajudar em uma pergunta (sobre outro assunto) mas que uma parte do codigo dele faz exatamente isso da uma [olhada nesse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252152/limpar-campo-file-quando-n%C3%A3o-tiver-mais-imagens/252156?noredirect=1#comment517390_252156), principalmente no metodo `handleFileSelect(evt)`. Perceba que ele esta usando  [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)